# Programs to Compile HTML from a Template

Tags: html, compilation

I'm working on a website that just uses HTML, CSS, and JS (no backend needed).  It's a simple site whose main purpose is to present information.  I have one standard template for all the pages (header, area for content, footer).  Right now, I have to copy and paste it into each page and update any changes to it manually on a page by page basis.

Are there any good programs out there that will allow me to:

- set a template
- write the content code for each page separately
- compile each page by inserting the content into the template (at a specified point)
- output the compilation into a third file

Bonus points for something that works similar to SASS where I can have the program watch a directory for changes and auto-compile files into another directory.

Bonus points for something that allows me to add in content at multiple sections.

I want to reiterate- I do not want to use a backend language (such as PHP or Django) that would stitch the pages together on the fly.  The site I'm working on doesn't need that, and it would negatively affect performance and maintainability.

Comment: Using a server side language would probably increase maintainability, and performance would be negligible.  Anyway, If you're on windows, you can use the `copy` command to create and append files, so write a batch file to do this for you.

Comment: You could create your pages as arrays in Javascript and single page parses "page" param in querystring and serves up correct "page".  You could also have various hidden DIVs using CSS and depending on #{somePage} in URL show/hide other DIVs.  Another option as mentioned is use a server side scripting language like PHP, JSP, ASP, Python, Perl, etc. and use "includes".

Comment: @Matthew How would that increase maintainability?  It adds a layer of complexity and another language for future devs to learn (I may not be the only one working on this site for its lifetime).

Comment: It reduces complexity by not having redundant code (even if that redundant code is automatically generated).  It also gives you better flexibility of your headers, perhaps on some pages you want the header to have navigation items highlighted indicating what page you're currently on.  Server processing languages like PHP, ASP, JSP exist for this very reason you're trying to solve (among other reasons).  As for potential developers to learn, I would be very suspect of their skills if they cannot figure out how to do a server side include regardless of whether they're fluent in it or not.

Comment: @Matthew Just for the record, I do know PHP and Django.  I'm not trying to debate on whether or not I should use them- I'm wondering if there is an HTML compiler.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at google closure templates https://developers.google.com/closure/templates/docs/helloworld_java

It takes soy files (templates) as input, then you can pass in whatever data you want and it'll merge the template with the data, generating the HTML.

You could also use PHP from the command line to generate the HTML http://php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.php

Answer (score 0):

if you want to stick to javascript you could use Jade (http://jade-lang.com) or another template engine with Node.js. 
Although it's server-side code, it's still js and not a third lang.